# Cursor is:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@428085b0

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy intentando hacer una validacion usando el cursor he igualandolo a null pero nunca me devuelve un valor null, siempre me devuelve un valor como este:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@428085b0

No se a que se deba, es algun error? o como puedo hacer una validacion igualando mi cursor a null.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando para mi consulta:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteData.query("usuarios", new String[]{"nombre_usuario", "password", "passwordr"}, "nombre_usuario = ? ", new String[]{nombreusu}, null, null, null, null);

                                if(cursor != null){

                                    try {
                                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                        values.put("nombre_usuario", nombreusu);
                                        values.put("password", passr);
                                        values.put("passwordr", passrr);

                                        sqLiteDatabase.insert("usuarios", null, values);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "El usuario se registro correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        obtenerNombreUsuario();
                                    }catch (SQLException e){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "El usuario ya existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }else{

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El usuario esta registrado"+cursor,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                                }
```

Comment: El mensaje que muestras como error en realidad no indica nada, busca siempre "Caused by".

Answer (score 0):

En realidad en este caso cursor no tiene valor de null, por eso no funciona correctamente tu validación, en este caso se usa :

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      ...
      ...
}
```

de esta forma si el cursor contiene valores, se lee cada valor en el bucle.

Otra forma es usar el método getCount(), claro previamente revisar si cursor no tiene valor null

```
 if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
```

Lo aplicarías de esta forma:

```
 if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El usuario esta registrado"+cursor,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                                }else{


                                    try {
                                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                        values.put("nombre_usuario", nombreusu);
                                        values.put("password", passr);
                                        values.put("passwordr", passrr);

                                        sqLiteDatabase.insert("usuarios", null, values);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "El usuario se registro correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        obtenerNombreUsuario();
                                    }catch (SQLException e){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "El usuario ya existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }


      }
```